# How to split sums of array with separator with Google App Script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I got an array from a single column from google sheet like `[[23],[25],[26],[89],[""],[45],[78],[62],[""],[123],[45],[68]]` How can I split it with empty values `[]` and get sums for each sub-array like (`163/185/236`) or more, cuz array length may be more then 1000 including 20-50 empty values?

I modified the script from the answer. But it doesn't work in my case. I don't understand why?

```js
function getSums(){
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sh = ss.getSheetByName('TemplateTest');
    var r = sh.getRange(1, 1, sh.getLastRow());
    var arr = r.getValues(); //log: [[23],[25],[26],[89],[""],[45],[78],[62],[""],[123],[45],[68]]
    var sums = [];
    var sum = 0;
    // iterate through the array
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i ++) {
         if (arr[i].length == 0 || i == arr.length - 1) {
             // empty array, push sum to array and reset
             sums.push(sum);
             sum = 0;
         } else {
        // array has values, sum them up and add to sum
             sum += arr[i].reduce((a, b) => a + b);
         }
    }
    Logger.log(sums) //log: [16345786212345]
}
```

Where I'm wrong and how can I fix it?

DEMO:

```js
function getSums(){
    //var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    //var sh = ss.getSheetByName('TemplateTest');
    //var r = sh.getRange(1, 1, sh.getLastRow());
    var arr = [[23],[25],[26],[89],[""],[45],[78],[62],[""],[123],[45],[68]]
    //var arr = r.getValues();
    var sums = [];
    var sum = 0;
    // iterate through the array
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i ++) {
         if (arr[i].length == 0 || i == arr.length - 1) {
             // empty array, push sum to array and reset
             sums.push(sum);
             sum = 0;
         } else {
        // array has values, sum them up and add to sum
             sum += arr[i].reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
         }
    }
    console.log(sums) //log: [16345786212345]
}
getSums();
```

Comment: Your code seems to work fine and it is logging `[516]` instead of `[16345786212345]`. I did add default value 0 in the `reduce()` method at last.

Comment: It works with snippet but doesn't when I'm getting an array from a column in Google Sheets. I don't understand why

Comment: The log is wrong. Try `console.log(JSON.stringify(arr))`

Comment: You are right! It was wrong! `[[23],[25],[26],[89],[""],[45],[78],[62],[""],[123],[45],[68]]`. But I don't see that with `Logger.log(arr)`

Comment: Now provide a demo snippet with your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could take a sinple loop and add the values until you reach `undefined` as value, then push the sum to the result set and reset `sum`.

At the end push the final sum to the result set, too.

```js
var data = [[23.0], [25.0], [26.0], [89.0], [""], [45.0], [78.0], [62.0], [""], [123.0], [45.0], [68.0]],
    result = [],
    sum = 0,
    value,
    i;

for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    value = data[i][0];
    if (value === "") {
        result.push(sum);
        sum = 0;
        continue;
    }
    sum += value;
}
result.push(sum);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: @Timo simple. Your demo is wrong and your simulating ``data`` is not representative.  Provide a proper demo

Answer (score 1):

Using `array.reduce`, It could be done very easily.

```js
const data = [
  [23.0],
  [25.0],
  [26.0],
  [89.0],
  [],
  [45.0],
  [78.0],
  [62.0],
  [],
  [123.0],
  [45.0],
  [68.0]
];
let [result, sum] = data.reduce(
  ([arr, sum], curr) => {
    if (curr.length) sum += curr[0];
    else arr.push(sum);
    return [arr, sum];
  },
  [[], 0]
);
result.push(sum); //push last data
console.log(result);
console.log(result.join("."));
```